# Call .NET 4.0 WPF Class Library From .NET 2.0 Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, dll

I have an application written in .NET 4.0 that i compile into a DLL file. I want to be able to use this DLL file in a Windows Forms .NET 2.0 application. I don't need the application to really interact much, except just passing a couple string values to the 4.0 DLL. The DLL is pretty much a bunch of Windows which i converted to UserControls and i just need to be able to reference them to display the UserControls from the 2.0 application without having to use a different exe and having to package them separately. What is the best way to do this? Because when i try to add the reference to the DLL to the 2.0 application, it gives me and error saying the DLL is built in a newer version of .NET so i can't do it that way. Is this where a COM object would come in? Any information and links i would really appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application can really and truly be called from a 2.0 application then the best approach is to compile it as a 2.0 application.  Visual Studio 2010 (and 2008) support the notion of multi-targetted solutions.  That is you can use it to compile a project for various versions of the CLR.

I would take the approach of compiling my application twice

- Once for 4.0
- Once for 2.0

This way you can use the DLL directly in your 2.0 application.  No messy COM tricks needed

Comment: well thats the thing. the DLL has to be .NET 4.0 and the calling application has to be .NET 2.0 for now at least. Its basically 2 applications based on different frameworks that i need to package as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a .ne 4.0 from a .net 2.0 is indeed possible. The problem is not that, but i dont think you can send the usercontrols across!

Im doing this in a couple of soultions where im passing simple classes from 4.0 to my 2.0 assemblies. The trick is to register the 4.0 assembly as a ServicedComponent (COM+), then share an interface (.net 20) betwewen these assemblies. Then in your .net 2.0 assembly instantiate the ServicedComponent and retrieve an instance of your interface from the "middleware" assembly.

As stated, you can only transfer interfaces through this, and marshalling a complex type as a UserControl i think will be very difficult.